# How do I stop CSS transitions from running the first time?

Tags: css, css-transitions

My site's menu changes to an off-canvas menu when the screen width is < 768px.  The menu can then be triggered by a click, and it `translate`s in and out using a CSS transition.

The problem is when a browser is > 768px, then gets resized to < 768px.  The menu quickly transitions out instead of initially being off-canvas.

You can see an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPoQzO (Code below)

1. Make the preview section really wide, and you'll see the white box fill the width
2. Resize the section narrow and you'll see it slide out.  I don't want that - I just want it to be instantly gone.
3. Clicking on the green area, you'll see the desired transition effect.
   *(This is, of course a bastardized representation, but it exemplifies the problem)*

I want to solve this (if possible) with just CSS.  I don't want to add a Javascript listener for resizing.  I'd rather have the effect continue, than use Javascript.

**Edit**: Here's the code:

```
<div id="menu">
  This is the menu
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
body{
  background:green;
}
#menu{
  background:white;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
    #menu{
        transform:translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
        transition:transform 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s;
    }

    #menu.in{
            transform:translateX(0);
            -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to achieve this with one more helper class that would set a transition:

```css
#menu {
  background:white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
  #menu.clicked {
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s;
  }
  #menu.in {
    transform:translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
  }
}
```

and JS part:

```
$(window).on('click',function() {
    $("#menu").toggleClass('in').addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#menu").removeClass('clicked');
    }, 100);
});
```

Note, that you need to remove helper class after some short timeout, so that the transition is only active in case of click, but not when window is resized.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOBYYP

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use Javascript to administer the transition.

Comment: On second thought - this is a pretty clean solution.

Comment: I used this technique with one change.  Rather than using a settimeout(), I just listened for the `transitionend` and `webkittransitionend` events.  This way the timing is entirely in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Moving `transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s; transition:transform 0.3s;` from inside the media query to the standard `#menu` seems to work, as shown:

From this:

```
#menu{
  background:white;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
    #menu{
        transform:translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
        transition:transform 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s;
    }

    #menu.in{
            transform:translateX(0);
            -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    }
}
```

To this:

```
#menu{
  background:white;
  transition:transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
    #menu{
        transform:translateX(-100%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
    }

    #menu.in{
            transform:translateX(0);
            -webkit-transform:translateX(0);
    }
}
```

This is because there is no transition property applied when the screen is wider than 768px; so it will suddenly jump instead of smoothly changing.

Comment: Comments are used to ask for more information, which I did not. I provided a solution which I believe to work so I gave an answer. It even says in the hint "Avoid answering questions in comments"

Comment: Appologies, it seems it was just my lagy laptop that made this work. Now that I'm on my PC I see @dfsq's answer does exactly what you need, OP.

Comment: Actually, @dfsq's answer uses Javascript, which I'd rather not use, but it is fairly clean, so I might anyway.  Yours doesn't work, because as soon as the screen gets resized <= 768px, the transformation is applied.  Since #menu has the transition applied always, I still get the animation.

Comment: Yeah it was due to the poor frame rate on my laptop; I just fluked it when testing and it appeared to work. I'm confused, you have Javascript in your example?

Comment: The javascript in my example is for toggling the menu in and out on mobile - not for detecting the size of the screen.

Since this has been on SO for a day, and the only viable answer is to use Javascript, I've decided to use @dfsq's (modified - see my comment) technique.

Comment: I had another go, without using much js (or at least without event listeners)

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand the question more clearly, you could try this:

```html
<style>
body{
  background:green;
}
#menu{
  background:white;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);
}
.out{
    transform:translateX(0%)!important;
    -webkit-   transform:translateX(-0%)!important;
}
@media(max-width:768px)
{
 #menu{ 
  transition:transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s;
  }
}
@media(min-width:786px)
{
  #menu{
    transform:translateX(0%);
    -webkit-   transform:translateX(-0%);
  }
}
</style>
<body onclick=" if(window.outerWidth < 786){document.querySelector('#menu') .classList.toggle('out');}">
<div id="menu">
  This is the menu
</div>
</body>
```

This method doesn't use any event listeners, and providing it's not inside a frame (where the outerWidth is not it's width), it seems to work.